# Oracle 10 column name resolution

Tags: oracle-10g

For example (just to illustrate the problem),

```
CREATE TABLE test_join(ID INT NOT NULL);
--1 
SELECT ID FROM 
test_join A
INNER JOIN test_join b ON 1=1;
--2 
SELECT ID FROM 
test_join A
INNER JOIN test_join b ON 1=1
INNER JOIN test_join c ON 1=1;
```

The first one gives expected "ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined". The second one executes without any complaints (Oracle 10g). 
I wonder if it's a bug or I'm missing something obvious in name resolution rules. Oracle 11 gives error in both cases.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's realistically a bug in whatever version of 10g you're using that would appear to be fixed in whatever version of 11g you're seeing an error on both statements.

I don't have a 10g database in front of me to test this.  I would wager, through, that you'd get an error in both cases if you used the old-style join syntax rather than the SQL 99 syntax.  That would imply that the problem is that Oracle wasn't translating from SQL 99 syntax to old-style syntax correctly and was missing the fact that the column was ambiguously defined.

Comment: You're 100% correct - it's a bug. I've read many blog posts and I think there was also a long discussion on oracle-l about it. This blog post http://hoopercharles.wordpress.com/2010/12/26/feeling-ansi-about-oracle-join-syntax/ has links to lots of Metalink bugs regarding ANSI joins.